# Return unique list that excludes another list

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, unique, transpose

I want to return a set of unique values with categorical variables across multiple columns that that excludes values from another list.

[image: Image link since I can't embed images in my question yet]

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({J2:J,K2:K},"select * where Col1 is not null"))
```

This properly returns the unique set of values with categorical variables but I can't seem to figure out how to exclude values from another list.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(J2:K,ISNA(MATCH(M2:N,J2:K,0))))
```

I've tried using this but it returns

```
#VALUE! FILTER range must be a single row or a single column.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qW84l-TEyBp14o7Vv11mgD3YyasoacBVblyXc3eOBE8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: are those columns a pair of items? or they are just items across two columns?

Comment: Yes, they are a pair of items. i.e. Expenses & Expenses1 should be considered as a unique entry and Expenses & Expenses2 should be another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(FILTER(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:B)), , 999^99)), NOT(COUNTIF(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(       D2:E) , , 999^99)), 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:B)), , 999^99))))), " ")))
```

[image: 0]

---

to account for items with spaces:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(SPLIT(FILTER(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:B," ","♦"))),,999^99)), NOT(COUNTIF(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(       SUBSTITUTE(D2:E," ","♦")) ,,999^99)), 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:B," ","♦"))),,999^99)))))," ")),"♦"," "))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks! This works for the sample data, but I can't use " " as a delimiter for the split function. How would you work around this?

Comment: Wow thanks! This does exactly what I want it to. I wanted to pull data that are nonadjacent columns from another sheet so I'm including that syntax if someone else has this question as well. {Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!G:G} Thanks again @player0